# How to correctly encodeURIComponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, x-www-form-urlencoded

In my work I need to use `encodeURIComponent`, but it's not in the correct structure, and the access to the endpoint doesn't work correctly.

In the images below you can see the differences between the structures of `header` of the current application, where the`encoded` is being done correctly. And my code, where the `encoded` is not being done correctly. I created a function to do this, but it's not working. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-leftpad-tklsvy?file=/src/App.js)

```js
  const BASE_URL = "";

  function encodeHeaders(headers) {
    let encodedHeaders = "";

    for (const key in headers) {
      encodedHeaders += encodeURIComponent(key + ": " + headers[key]) + "%0A";
    }

    return encodedHeaders;
  }

  const headers = {
    Connection: "close",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-EES-AUTH-CLIENT-ID": "o75j23m4c2m3e411sb7z",
    "X-EES-AUTH-HASH":
      "e782225331d2839774aac84eab2762a9c8059cfc7433af8f178138ab426fbfbf",
    accept: "application/json"
  };

  const requestData = {
    code: "ee",
    branch: "119",
    till: "7",
    serial: "912347",
    url: "https://resources.sandbox",
    method: "GET",
    header: encodeHeaders(headers)
  };

  /**
   * Example of how I am using the application in a real test
   */
  function getTestService() {
    return axios
      .post(BASE_URL, requestData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      });
  }
```

**Here's what I get vs what I expect:**

```
What I get (before and after encoded)

header: Connection%3A%20close%0AContent-Type%3A%20application%2Fjson%0AX-EES-AUTH-CLIENT-ID%3A%20o75j23m4c2m3e411sb7z%0AX-EES-AUTH-HASH%3A%20e782225331d2839774aac84eab2762a9c8059cfc7433af8f178138ab426fbfbf%0Aaccept%3A%20application%2Fjson%0A

Connection%253A%2520close%250AContent-Type%253A%2520application%252Fjson%250AX-EES-AUTH-CLIENT-ID%253A%2520o75j23m4c2m3e411sb7z%250AX-EES-AUTH-HASH%253A%2520e782225331d2839774aac84eab2762a9c8059cfc7433af8f178138ab426fbfbf%250Aaccept%253A%2520application%252Fjson%250A
```

```
What I expect (before and after encoded)

header: Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
X-EES-AUTH-CLIENT-ID: o75j23m4c2m3e411sb7z
X-EES-AUTH-HASH: e782225331d2839774aac84eab2762a9c8059cfc7433af8f178138ab426fbfbf
accept: application/json

Connection%3A+close%0AContent-Type%3A+application%2Fjson%0AX-EES-AUTH-CLIENT-ID%3A+o75j23m4c2m3e411sb7z%0AX-EES-AUTH-HASH%3A+e782225331d2839774aac84eab2762a9c8059cfc7433af8f178138ab426fbfbf%0Aaccept%3A+application%2Fjson
```

[image]

It is possible to notice the difference between the structures of each of the `headers`. Before and after encoded.

[image]

Comment: can you add to the question, in TEXT (not a picture) what you get vs what you expect

Comment: Hi Jaromanda X, I updated the question. Thank you

Comment: The `headers` structure is being send to the server as form data not as headers.  If that’s as expected then know that form data is automatically url encoded for you by axios.  Your result is consistent with that data having been url encoded twice.